# how to integre apache flink and kafka?

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-flink

i create my script java to stream enents from producer kafka to print with flink, my code is runing on my cluster but it does not display the message console.
in the next my java code to stream from kafka to print in console :

```
package com.flink;
import org.apache.flink.api.common.functions.MapFunction;
import org.apache.flink.api.java.utils.ParameterTool;
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.datastream.DataStream;
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.environment.StreamExecutionEnvironment;
import org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.kafka.FlinkKafkaConsumer082;
import org.apache.flink.streaming.util.serialization.SimpleStringSchema;

public class ReadFromKafka {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        // create execution environment
        StreamExecutionEnvironment env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();
                  // my parametres ever runin the job :
                 //--topic test --bootstrap.servers 192.168.3.152:9092 --zookeeper.connect 192.168.3.152:2181 --group.id group_test
        // parse user parameters
        ParameterTool parameterTool = ParameterTool.fromArgs(args);

        DataStream<String> messageStream = env.addSource(new FlinkKafkaConsumer082<>(parameterTool.getRequired("topic"), new SimpleStringSchema(), parameterTool.getProperties()));

        messageStream.rebalance().map(new MapFunction<String, String>() {
            private static final long serialVersionUID = -6867736771747690202L;

            @Override
            public String map(String value) throws Exception {
                return "Kafka and Flink says: " + value;
            }
        }).print();

        env.execute();
    }
}
```

Comment: If you run on a cluster, console output is piped into a file. See `log` folder of the TaskManager that runs your code.

Comment: a sse the log folder I have found nothing,even in batch mode it works with the word count it view the results in the console.